# Parameters on Pentaho not working when inside of braces

Tags: postgresql, escaping, pentaho

I am trying to perform a simple postgresql task with Pentaho. I need to update a jsonb value, based on a user's input. So it looks like:

```
UPDATE table
set column = jsonb_set(
    column,
    '{path}',
    '${new_param_value}'
)
WHERE id = ${id_param}
```

I added an alert and checked the network call, both indicating the correct parameter values are being passed. However, the value is never updated. If I substitute the user's entered param value with a hard coded number, it works as expected.

Ex: Value is updated successfully to 3, regardless of input

```
UPDATE table
set column = jsonb_set(
    column,
    '{path}',
    '3'
)
WHERE id = ${id_param}
```

I guess that there is an issue with finding the parameter when it is inside of {} braces. I've tried using ` tick marks to account for this, and using a WITH clause before my statement, but am still stuck. Any suggestion helps!

Comment: use ${new_param_value} without '' and try it

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately did not help.